# How do I pass a playframework template list item variable as input to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

Sorry if this is trivial or having been asked before using a different terminology. Im relatively new to web programming and specially to play framework.

My scala web template looks like:

```
@(alarms: List[Alarm], alarmForm: Form[Alarm]) 

@import helper._

@main("Alarm list") { 
    <script id="showInfoScript" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function showInfoFromAlarm(alarm) {
       $("#patientName").text(alarm.Patient.name);
    };
    </script>


    <header>
        <h1> EMHT </h1>
    </header>

 <div class="collumnsContainer">    
    <div> <section class="alarmListSection">
        <h2>@alarms.size() alarm(s)</h2>

        <div class="list-group">
        @for(alarm <- alarms){
          <a href="#" onclick="showInfoScript(@alarm);return false;" class="list-group-item active">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">@{alarm.id} of type @{alarm.`type`} </h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Callee @{alarm.callee.phoneNumber} ;Patient @{alarm.patient.personalNumber} </p>
          </a>
         }  
        </div>

    </section></div>
```

where I basically try to have each button created in the `@for(alarm <- alarms)` to call the javascript function `showInfoScript` with the alarm object instance corresponding to that button.

As it is the code fails. I understand that the problem is that the object in the for loop is a scala object and it need some sort of conversion to be passed to the javascript function.

But what would be the simplest way to convert it to something understandable by the javascript? I thought of json and I've read about doing a `@Json.toJson(alarm)`, but I got an error that there were no serializer and that Id need to "implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type".

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you have a clear grasp about the difference between the Scala code and the JavaScript code, the Scala code is executed serverside to render html, that html is sent to the client where the javascript is executed. If you want to pass data from your scala code to JavaScript you basically have two options:

1. serialize the data inside your html document, for example as JSON, but you could also do it as data-attributes on tags, script blocks with function calls etc. that you generate with your play template.
2. provide a separate http url where you can load the data with a request from you JavaScript

The error you get when you try to use Json.toJson is that there is no way for play to know how you want an instance of Alarm mapped to JSON, so if you want to do it like that you need to define a `Writes[Alarm]` that play can use. Look at the play docs about json for more information about that. (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson)

Comment: thanks for the answer. In that sense could I specify the mapping between object and json in the play template (or an imported play template) and have the conversion done there and generated when the code is run on serverside? I'm actually writting the back-end code in java, and though I've seen in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJsonRequests how to send json to the template from java, for some parts of the template it would be perhaps easier and more convenient to send as java object and have the relevant sub-object converted to json there.

Comment: Ah, sorry I took for granted you were using Scala for some reason. Then there is a different API for doing javascript serialization (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJsonRequests), not sure how that works or how to apply it for json you want to put in a template though. One idea could be to serialize to json in your controller and use the @Html-helper method to render it unescaped in the template.